# OpenCover.Console.exe - Incorrect Arguments: The argument 'xxx.' is not recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, code-coverage, opencover, codecov

I am implementing CodeCov for code coverage in c# with Visual Studio 2019 and I am using OpenCover and Xunit. My solution has two projects (Crossroads and CrossroadsUnitTests)

I have added the required nuget packages to the solution (OpenCover, xunit, xunit.runner.console, xunit.runner.visualstudio) and I want to run the OpenCover command locally to generate a coverage report but it seems I am having spaces in my path.

Below is the command I run in the Package Manager and the error i receive;

```
PM> OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:\Users\Mr. Erbynn\.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.console\2.4.1\tools\net46\xunit.console.exe" -targetargs:"C:\Users\Mr. Erbynn\source\repos\Crossroads\CrossroadsUnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CrossroadsUnitTests.dll -noshadow" -output:".\coverage.xml" -filter:"+[Crossroads*]* -[CrossroadsUnitTests*]*"
```

[image]

I have tried escaping with `\"` but it's not working.

Below are the command and error I receive in power shell when I run OpenCover in the root solution folder

```
 C:\Users\\"Mr. Erbynn\"\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:\Users\\"Mr. Erbynn\"\.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.console\2.4.1\tools\net46\xunit.console.exe" -targetargs:"C:\Users\\"Mr. Erbynn\"\source\repos\Crossroads\CrossroadsUnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CrossroadsUnitTests.dll -noshadow" -output:".\coverage.xml" -filter:"+[Crossroads*]* -[CrossroadsUnitTests*]*"
```

[image]

Below is the target test dll file hopefully;
[image]

Please any help or suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage#notes-on-spaces-in-arguments)

> If your argument needs to escape quotes i.e. to pass arguments with spaces to that target process then you can use `\"` i.e. `-targetargs:"\"c:\program files\" xyz"`

So, your `-targetargs` should look like this :

```
//           vv---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------vv
-targetargs:"\"C:\Users\Mr. Erbynn\source\repos\Crossroads\CrossroadsUnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CrossroadsUnitTests.dll\" -noshadow"
```

Comment: ohk...alright @Cid. And how about with the `-target`, does it needs to be tweaked cus  I seem to be getting similar error again - `Incorrect Arguments: The argument 'C:\Users\Mr.' is not recognised`